# What would be the easiest function to double given attributes in a class

Tags: python-3.x

I am extremely new to python and am trying to write a function that doubles the attributes that are given in a class. I realize that I am able to achieve this by simply multiplying each attribute by two, but am wondering if someone can show me a method that is more efficient.

The class I am working with is:

```
class Ingredients:

bread = Ingredients()

bread.flour=2
bread.milk=0.5
bread.salt=1
bread.butter=4
bread.yeast=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the `__mul__` method in your class to allow it to handle multiplication. Personally i think you need to think about your class design more rather then just creating arbitrary attributes. However based on your question the following could be used

```py
class Ingredients:
    def __mul__(self, num):
        for ingredient in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[ingredient] *= num

    def __str__(self):
        output = "Ingredients:\n"
        for ingredient in self.__dict__:
            output += ingredient + " " + str(self.__dict__[ingredient]) + "\n"
        return output

bread = Ingredients()

bread.flour=2
bread.milk=0.5
bread.salt=1
bread.butter=4
bread.yeast=1
print(bread)

bread * 2
print(bread)

bread * 10
print(bread)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Ingredients:
flour 2
milk 0.5
salt 1
butter 4
yeast 1

Ingredients:
flour 4
milk 1.0
salt 2
butter 8
yeast 2

Ingredients:
flour 40
milk 10.0
salt 20
butter 80
yeast 20
```

If you want just a method that will double then you could just use

```py
    def double_ingredients(self):
        for ingredient in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[ingredient] *= 2
```

and call it like `bread.double_ingredients()`

Comment: This is for a project in my introduction to python course, so unfortunately the class was provided to me in the assignment. I am more so looking for a basic method of doubling the attributes within one function. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Then you can just use the `double_ingredients` method I added at the end

Comment: I'm not getting any output when I try that function, just "Process finished with exit code 0."

Comment: Well the method doesn't return anything it just doubles everything. Which is what you asked in your question

Comment: How could I go about getting the function to output the doubled attributes? Or would I need to use the first method if I wanted that? My bad for asking a million questions, this is all new to me.

Comment: So generally if a function modifies values of an object it doesnt normally return them. since the object is already modified. If a function takes an object and generates some new values without changing the original object then it would return the new values.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So maybe I misunderstood when my professor asked for a function that "Takes bread and doubles all its attributes." I took that as he wanted a function that took the attributes and multiplied them by two.

Comment: thats what my double_ingredients function does. It multplies all the attributes by 2.

Comment: Oh okay so I was right haha. The function just doesn't display anything when it is called.

Comment: correct it modifies the attribute of the object the function belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something for each attribute of an object, then it makes more sense to use a dictionary rather than an object. Python has a special kind of dictionary named `Counter` for doing arithmetic on multiple properties at once:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> bread = Counter({ 'flour': 2, 'milk': 0.5, 'salt': 1, 'butter': 4, 'yeast': 1 })
>>> bread + bread
Counter({'butter': 8, 'flour': 4, 'salt': 2, 'yeast': 2, 'milk': 1.0})
```

This works for doubling, but unfortunately you can't multiply like `bread * 2`, so if you want to multiply by some other factor, lets say 15, then you could do this with a dict comprehension:

```
>>> { k: 15 * v for k, v in bread.items() }
{'butter': 60, 'flour': 30, 'salt': 15, 'yeast': 15, 'milk': 7.5}
```